# Behave differently when selecting a dropdown select by click or arrow keys

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<select id="s">
<option value="1">selected1</option>
<option value="2">selected2</option>
<option value="3">selected3</option>
<option value="4">selected4</option>
</select>
<div id="se">
</div>

$('body').on('change', '#s', function() {
    $('#se').text($('#s :selected').text()+" / unfortunatly it also triggers when Im moving with the UP and DOWN keys, not just with select");
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8kLke2je/

I want this event triggered if I pick an item from the dropbox with mouseclick and not with UP and DOWN arrows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the "click" event on the select:

```
    $('#s').click(function(){
            var sv = $('#s').val();
            $('#se').html("That\'s it: "+sv);
    });
```

Here there is a fiddle for it: https://jsfiddle.net/nemoneminis/rwza9xzt/1/

Answer (score 1):

`.on` passes the event into the callback function.  You can utilize that to detect whether it was a click or keypress.

If you bind separately to `click` and `keyup`, you can detect which one by checking the event type:

```
$(document).on('click keyup', '#s', function(e) {
    if ('click' == e.type) {
        $('#se').text($('#s :selected').text());
    }
});
```